# How to access navigation object in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react-navigation and I'm trying to implement a simple navigation. The problem that I'm having is that I can't find a way to pass "navigation" object to a desire screen. I tried using withNavigation etc.. it is still throwing "this.props.navigation" is not defined!. From what i've read if I declare a screen in the rootStack, the navigation object is automatically passed to the component right?

**so here is my rootStack**

```js
/* ROUTING RULES */
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Main: Main,
      ChatBox: ChatBox,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
      
     }
    

   
  );
/* End */
```

and this is the method that I'm using to navigate the chatbox screen

```js
()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ChatBox', {
                avatarUrl: matches.avatarUrl,
                name: matches.name,
              })
```

I noticed that from my Main screen, I could access the navigation without any problems, but when I tried to execute a simple console.log in my chatBox screen

```js
  constructor(props){
   super()
  console.log(this.props.navigation)
  
  }
```

I'm getting **"TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating'_this.props.navigation')"**

Can someone help me to solve this mystery ?? thanks :)

Comment: How are you moving to ChatBox screen? can you share your code snippet for that?

Comment: @DNA.h yep sure.. I've added the missing code, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use life cycle methods instead of constructor

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.navigation)
}
```

Comment: Hey Tareq, your solution works! erm can you provide an explanation :D

Comment: because `this.props` is set up by React itself as a part of the job it does under the hood, so using it inside Life Cycle methods is not only the better practice, it also make sense, the first life cycle method fires when react becomes ready, constructor is just for setting class properties like state, and since props is React job to set, trying to use it from constructor is not a good idea because there’s a chance that React isn’t ready yet and didn’t get the chance to do its job under the hood

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help (flex) :D

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you don't need this to access props. Try this

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props.navigation.getParam('avatarUrl');
}
```

EDIT: you had to pass props to super too! not sending it may cayses some errors.

Comment: It is still throwing "Invariant Violation:element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function...."

Comment: I am highly suspicious about second argument. probably it's related to another part of code. can you share more of your code?